# Is there a way to make multiple columns NOT NULL in one command?

Tags: mysql

Pretty straightforward. I've been reading the `ALTER` documentation and searching on this site as well as others looking for a less time consuming way to change my table properties. I made the mistake of making all of my columns `NULL` instead of `NOT NULL` when creating my tables and want to change them all. There is no data in them, so what I've been doing is:

```
ALTER TABLE DB.TABLE MODIFY COLUMN TINYINT(1) NOT NULL;
```

The types of the fields vary from `TINYINT(1)`, `VARCHAR(256)`, `VARCHAR(512)`, `VARCHAR(1024)` and `VARCHAR(10000)` so something like DB.* would work because I need to specify the column's type with this command.

Is there a method of doing this? Just change the "NULL" property of each column, ignoring the rest of information altogether?

Thanks!

Comment: Not as far as I know, sorry.

Comment: These are the kinds of things that are more easily done in a GUI tool like MySQL Query Browser or PHPMyAdmin where you just click a check box to alter that property. It writes the SQL for you.

Comment: Yeah I used to use heidisql until I installed redhat. Haven't gotten around to installing one since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

1. since you said `There is no data in them`; you can re-create the table again by dropping the existing one and re-create it.
2. Fire `ALTER` command for all the columns separately.

I would go for the 1st option in this case to save time.

Comment: Yeah was just waiting for the timer